# Angular Porque no se queda almacenado el resultado de una peticion http en el array que lo estoy guardando

Tags: angular, http

En el codigo que muestro a continuacion trato de hacer una **peticion http** la cual funciona perfectamente, pero a la hora de **almacenarla en un array** solo se queda almacenada el tiempo dura el **ambito de la funcion** :

`this.usuarioService.getAll().subscribe(...`

Hablo de mi `array` =  `public lista_usuarios: {};` en el cual almaceno los datos que recibo de mi **API** pero **solo se quedan almacenados el tiempo que dura la funcion** , para saber eso he hecho un `console.log()` del array **justo despues de asignar el valor** y tambien en **ngOnInit** despues de llamar a la funcion que carga el array.

Que pudiera ser lo que provoca que al final el `Observable` **elimine** el contenido de mi `Array`

```
  import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Usuario } from "../models/usuario";
import { usuarioService } from "../services/usuario.services";

@Component({
  selector: "app-listar-usuarios",
  templateUrl: "./listar-usuarios.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./listar-usuarios.component.css"],
  providers: [usuarioService]
})
export class ListarUsuariosComponent implements OnInit {
  public lista_usuarios: {};

  constructor(private usuarioService: usuarioService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.cargarUsuarios();

    console.log(
      "Lista usuarios (despues de  funcion http): ",
      this.lista_usuarios
    );
  }

  cargarUsuarios() {
    console.log("ABAJO");
    this.usuarioService.getAll().subscribe(
      usuarios => {
        this.lista_usuarios = usuarios;
        console.log(
          "Lista usuarios (dentro funcion http): ",
          this.lista_usuarios
        );
      },
      error => {
        console.log("ERROR => " + error);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Añadir que si **hardcodeo** las inserciones de la lista de objetos me crea la tabla perfectamente.

Comment: Hola, tú función   this.usuarioService.getAll() es asincrona, es decir seguidamente va a ejuctar tu console.log(
      "Lista usuarios (despues de  funcion http): ",
      this.lista_usuarios
    );, en ese momento puede que la lista this.usuario aun no esté cargada. Saludos

Comment: Hola @cjara , gracias por responder, eso pensaba yo que era asincrona, pero siempre lo he hecho parecido a esto, como podria solucionarlo ??

Comment: en teoria con el `subcscribe` deberia solventar mi problema porque eso controla la asincronia al hacer la peticion a la API . Pero no lo esta haciendo

Comment: Si, pero el console.log que continua se está ejecutando de manera linea, primero cargarUsuarios() y seguidamente el console, podrias declarar como observable lista_usuarios y suscribirte ante algún cambio para imprimir su valor.

Answer (score 0):

Hola existen varias cuestiones, la primera es que no estas declarando un arreglo sino un objeto aquí: `public lista_usuarios: {};`
Deberías crear algo asi `public userList: User[] = []` donde `User` es el tipo de la variable, aunque en este caso estoy asumiendo que es User pero seria el que utilices o any sino utilizas ninguno

La segunda cuestión es que los observables en angular son asíncronos, esto quiere decir que no devuelven el valor instantáneamente, este es un tema difícil de entender, por lo que te recomiendo este [enlace](https://desarrolloweb.com/articulos/introduccion-teorica-observables-angular.html).
En conclusión tu console.log dentro de OnInit nunca va a ser ejecutado luego del subscribe y por tanto el valor de la lista es la anterior a la llamada al observable.